# Running code after Rails is done loading?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

I have a periodic task that needs to execute once a minute (using delayed_job). I would like for Rails to automatically queue it up as soon as it's finished loading, if one such task isn't already present in the system.

What is a good place for me to run some code right at the end of the entire Rails boot flow? Someone suggested config/environments/development.rb (or other environment), but delayed_job give me ActiveRecord issues when I queue up jobs from there.

I consulted http://guides.rubyonrails.org/initialization.html, and there doesn't seem to be a clear location for that kind of code either.

Is this kind of post-deployment setup to be done perhaps externally to my app's code, maybe through rake or some other means? Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Regarding http://guides.rubyonrails.org/initialization.html, sorry, we're working hard to rewrite it. For your problem, I would try with `config.after_initialize` in your application.rb

```
def after_initialize(&block)
  ActiveSupport.on_load(:after_initialize, :yield => true, &block)
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Add your code in the initializer directory.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#using-initializer-files

Comment: Also, if code in question must execute absolute last, you can make an initializer called `zzz.rb` or somesuch that will be last in alphabetical order and thus Rails will execute it last. Alternatively `_me_first.rb` initializers can be placed first.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options really

1) add it into initializers directory and this should be ok.

2) add it at the very end of application.rb, this is less clean but it will have things like initializers ready at this point ;p so if 1) fails because of AR problems do 2)