# ActiveJob: start a job automatically when starting server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, rails-activejob

For example I have a job that I want recurrence every 1 hour. Here is my code:

```
class NewsletterJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  after_perform do |job|
     NewsletterJob.set(wait: 1.hour).perform_later user
  end

  def perform(*args)
    puts "I am busy mailing newsletter."
  end
end
```

My question is: How can I call above code that is satisfied 2 conditions:

- run automatically when server is started.
- run only once. For example, I use sidekiq for message queue. So I want the next time restart server, only one instance of job is available.

Comment: This question can probably be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10972450/running-code-after-rails-is-done-loading

Answer (score 0):

There are a list of cron projects here https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Related-Projects#recurring-jobs